How to Set Background Color on QTableView Cell
I'm trying to set the background color on a cell in QTableView.  Below I'm including the code that I'm using to set the color. When I click in column 5, the color dialog pops up and I can select a color, but that's as far as it goes. It does not paint the cell.
self.tv_referrals.clicked.connect(self.changeColor)
def changeColor(self, index):
    col = index.column()
    if col == 5:
        color = QColorDialog.getColor()
        if color.isValid():
            row = index.row()
            self.model.setColor(row, col, color)


setColor is being called in the PandasModel successfully.*

class PandasModel(QAbstractTableModel):
dataChanged = Signal(QModelIndex, QModelIndex, list)
def __init__(self, data_frame, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.data_frame = data_frame
    self.colors = dict()
def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
    return len(self.data_frame)

def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
    return len(self.data_frame.columns)

def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        row, col = index.row(), index.column()
        return str(self.data_frame.iat[row, col])
    if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
        if index.row() % 2 == 0:
            color = QColor("#f5f5f0")
        else:
            color = QColor("#ffffff")
        return color

def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return str(self.data_frame.columns[section])
        elif orientation == Qt.Vertical:
            return str(section + 1)

def addRow(self, row_data):
    self.beginInsertRows(self.index(self.rowCount(), 0), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
    self.data_frame.loc[self.rowCount()] = row_data
    self.endInsertRows()

def removeRow(self, row_data):
    self.beginRemoveRows(self.index(self.rowCount(), 0), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
    self.data_frame.loc[self.rowCount()] = row_data
    self.endRemoveRows()

def flags(self, index):
    if not index.isValid():
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled
    return super().flags(index) | Qt.ItemIsEditable

def setData(self, index, value, role):
    if role == Qt.EditRole:
        print("In SetData")
        if index.column() == 3:
            self.data_frame.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = value.upper()
        else:
            self.data_frame.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [Qt.DisplayRole])
        return True
    return False

def setColor(self, row, column, color):
    ix = self.index(row, column)
    self.colors[(row, column)] = color
    self.dataChanged.emit(ix, ix, (Qt.BackgroundRole,))


After many hours trying to fix this on my own, I ended up praying and asking for help.  (I should have prayed much earlier.)  Soon afterward I found a similar solution online that helped me.  Below are the changes that I made to my code that worked.
I call setData instead of setColor.
self.model.setData(index, color, Qt.ItemDataRole.BackgroundRole)
In the QabstractModel, I removed the setColor function.  I also changed the following:
def data(self, index, role=Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
    if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
        row, col = index.row(), index.column()
        return str(self.data_frame.iat[row, col])
    if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.BackgroundRole:
        if index.row() % 2 == 0:
            color = QColor("#f5f5f0")
        else:
            color = QColor("#ffffff")
        return self.colors.get((index.row(), index.column()), color)
    return None

def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
    if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return str(self.data_frame.columns[section])
        elif orientation == Qt.Vertical:
            return str(section + 1)

def setData(self, index, value, role):
    if role == Qt.EditRole:
        print("In SetData")
        if index.column() == 3:
            self.data_frame.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = value.upper()
        else:
            self.data_frame.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [Qt.DisplayRole])
        return True
    if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.BackgroundRole:
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        self.colors[(row, column)] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, (Qt.ItemDataRole.BackgroundRole,))
        return True
    return False

